# Rails/Cancancan: Define ability with a complex/scoped query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cancancan

I am building an app in Rails 4 using Cancancan for role authorization. I have an ability defined that works for individual records but not the :index action.

I have a user role called 'RVSP'. RVSPs are assigned `WorkOrders`, from which the RVSP will create a `Record`.

```rb
class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :record
  belongs_to :rvsp, class_name: "User"
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :work_order
end
```

Here's my problem: I want RVSP users to be able to read or update `Records` where the `WorkOrder` was assigned to that RVSP. Here's the ability definition so far:

```rb
can [:read, :update], Record, Record.for_rvsp(user.id) do |record|
  work_order = record.work_order
  user.id == work_order.rvsp_id
end
```

The scope `Record.for_rvsp` is this monstrosity:

```rb
scope :for_rvsp, -> (rvsp_id) { where( work_order: { rvsp: { id: rvsp_id } } ) }
```

So: How do I define the ability and/or query for all `Records` where the `Record's` `WorkOrder's` `rvsp_id` matches the current user's id? I suspect it's a join of some kind but I'm new to this and haven't done that before.

P.S. I thought of just adding a `created_by` column to `Record`, but I already have that through PaperTrail, which I'm using for an audit trail. But `Record.versions.first.whodunnit` is about the same as `Record.work_order.rvsp_id` as far as difficulty of the query is concerned. Thanks for any advice you can offer!

P.P.S. I'm using Postgres but I'd rather not do any database-specific SQL if I can avoid it.

Comment: Why this doesn't work ? :`can [:read, :update], Record, work_order: { rvsp: {id: user.id} }`

Answer (score 2):

I started banging on joins and it seems to be working! I replaced the scope above with the following class method:

```rb
def self.for_rvsp(rvsp_id)
  joins(:work_order).where(work_orders: {rvsp_id: rvsp_id})
end
```

I also tidied up the ability in Ability.rb:

```rb
can [:read, :update], Record, Record.for_rvsp(user.id) do |record|
  user.id == record.work_order.rvsp_id
end
```

So, as far as index actions are concerned, it appears that you need to do the same thing in two places: you define a scope that fetches the records you need, and then you define the ability in the block. The scope ensures that you load all the right records, and the ability block authorizes them. Seems to work for me anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but you can traverse the associations in CanCanCan.

`can [:read, :update], Record, work_order: { rsvp_id: user.id }`